# How to write Haskell partial functions that will never have invalid values?

Tags: function, haskell, partial-functions

Let's say want a function, taking a list of numbers, that returns the sum of adjacent pairs of numbers, except at the two edges where it simply returns the edge numbers. For example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] --> [1,3,5,7,9,5]
```

I come up with the following function:

```
p1 :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
p1 []         = []
p1 (x:xs)     = x:p2 (x:xs)

p2 :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
p2 [x]        = [x]
p2 (x1:x2:xs) = (x1+x2):p2 (x2:xs)
```

*(never mind if there is a better way to do this ...)*

`p2` is only ever called by `p1`. `p2` will also never be called with an empty list, only with lists at least one element. However, `p2` is still a partial function, and it will trigger a non-exhaustive pattern match warning with `ghc -Wall`.

What is the accepted way to deal with this? Do I just not write the `p2 []` case? Or `p2 [] = undefined`, or `p2 [] = unused_value`, or something else?

Comment: Put `p2` in a `where` statement of `p1`.

Answer (score 2):

The most common approach is to put in a final case like

```
p2 [] = error "impossible! p2 received an empty list"
```

It should include sufficient information to track down the source of the problem in the error message. It's not ideal, though. People (including me) do it because it's a practical solution to a real problem. But sometimes code evolves and you end up in that case, and figuring out why is a debugging mess.

It's far better to eliminate the problem by changing the boundary conditions to total functions:

```
p1 :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
p1 xs = zipWith (+) xs' $ tail xs'
  where
    xs' = [0] ++ xs ++ [0]
```

Now you know that no amount of refactoring can trigger a hidden error case, because there isn't a hidden error case.

Of course this sort of transformation isn't always possible. But it often is, and it's always worth spending a minute searching for.  You'll either find a better approach, or have come up with a reason why the function is partial to include in the comments.

Comment: This is a pet peeve of mine. Leaving out the case provides a useful error at runtime carrying file+line info, but triggers a compile time warning. Adding the case requires me to add such info manually to the error string. I'd argue that `error` should always report file+line info. (I know there's some CPP macro that can do that, but I'd like this to be the default)

Answer (score 2):

You can make `p2` total by using a non-empty list type. Or, inlining and uncurrying the standard non-empty list type `(a, [a])`, you can write something like:

```
p2 :: Num a => a -> [a] -> [a]
p2 x []      = [x]
p2 x (x':xs) = (x+x'):p2 x' xs
```

You will of course have to modify `p1` slightly to match:

```
p1 :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
p1 []         = []
p1 (x:xs)     = x:p2 x xs -- the call to p2 on this line changed
```